# Path: Data Analysis in R

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-science

I am building a path for beginners (like me) to guide them through the learning of data analysis in R (Only in R please).

Would you suggest me any new sections and/or new courses that i should add?

Heres is what i have been adding till now: http://studiy.co/path/data-analysis/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can check datacamp https://www.datacamp.com/courses

Comment: Garrett and Hadley cover this, [link](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

Comment: Wonderful! Many thanks @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need to distinguish... If you want just to learn R programming you may check Coursera course on R

https://www.coursera.org/learn/r-programming

that would give you some basics. If you need to learn how to analyse data then you may need a bit more. What are your background in mathematics? What kind of statistics know-how do you have? A GREAT resource in my opinion is the book

An Introduction to Statistical Learning with applications in R

That you can even find for free in pdf (http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/). Beware that you may need some mathematics background to be able to understand it fully. In case you have a more profound background in science I may have other suggestions. Could you tell us at what level are you?
Hope that helps.